# Does Net Investment Income Tax (NIIT) apply to short-term capital gains

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax

I'm trying to figure out the maximum effective US federal marginal tax rate for short-term capital gains.  In other words, how much more federal income tax would someone owe who incurs a $3M net short-term capital gain instead of a $2M one.

In some places I've read that short-term capital gains are taxed "just like income," suggesting a 35% marginal rate in 2018.  In others places, people say that NIIT applies to all passive income, which suggests a 35% + 3.8% = 38.8% marginal rate.  If there are other applicable taxes such as medicare, I would like to know about those, too.

It's very hard to find examples of this worked out, because so much of the content I find is about convincing people to take long-term capital gains (at 23.8%).  I'm well aware that long-term capital gains are better than short-term, but am missing information to calculate exactly how much better.

Comment: [Yes NIIT includes capital gain regardless of duration (but not the excluded amount on sale of your home), and no Additional Medicare Tax (like normal FICA/SECA) does not include any investment income.](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/net-investment-income-tax) But if you have $2M gain you can afford advice from someone more qualified than a dog on the Internet.

Comment: The comment about being able to afford advice based on hypothetical example is unnecessary.  This is theoretical discussion, not real money.  The actual gain may or may not be real.  The people who find this question and answer later may or may not have access to someone "more qualified"...

Answer (score 2):

So yes it turns out that the 3.8% NIIT applies to both short- and long-term capital gains.  However, it doesn't mean that short-term capital gains are taxed higher than income, but rather the same.  Self-employment income is subject to a 2.9% medicare and an 0.9% supplemental medicare tax.  So NIIT just makes up for the lack of self-employment tax on capital gains.

Comment: That's only if it's self-employment income and only if the income is subject to FICA. If either is not true, then STCG subject to NIIT is taxed more than ordinary income.